# Select default option value from typescript angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown

I have a select html like this:

```
<select ng-model='nrSelect' class='form-control'>                                                                
    <option value='47'>47</option>
    <option value='46'>46</option>
    <option value='45'>45</option>
</select>
```

How can I select the default value from typescript for example 47 ?

Comment: Set `nrSelect` to the default value. By the way, if you want binding to work, you ned to change it to `[(ngModel)]` as well

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<select  class='form-control' 
        (change)="ChangingValue($event)" [value]='46'>
  <option value='47'>47</option>
  <option value='46'>46</option>
  <option value='45'>45</option>
</select>

// Note: You can set the value of select only from options tag. In the above example, you cannot set the value of select to anything other than 45, 46, 47.
```

[Here, you can ply with this.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwdref?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 50):

> app.component.html

```
<select [(ngModel)]='nrSelect' class='form-control'>
  <option value='47'>47</option>
  <option value='46'>46</option>
  <option value='45'>45</option>
</select>
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  nrSelect = 47
}
```

Answer (score 28):

For reactive form, I managed to make it work by using the following example (47 can be replaced with other value or variable):

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <select formControlName="fieldName">
    <option
        *ngFor="let option of options; index as i"
        [selected]="option === 47"
    >
        {{ option }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this on Angular 11. Not working. I solved the issue by setting on the class side:

this.form.setValue({fieldName: 47});

Answer (score 10):

Correct Way would be :

```
<select id="select-type-basic" [(ngModel)]="status">
    <option *ngFor="let status_item of status_values">
    {{status_item}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Value Should be avoided inside option if the value is to be dynamic,since that will set the default value of the 'Select field'. Default Selection should be binded with [(ngModel)] and Options should be declared likewise.

```
status : any = "47";
status_values: any = ["45", "46", "47"];
```

Answer (score 9):

In case you use Angular's **`FormBuilder`** this is the way to go (at least for **Angular 9**):

#### HTML view: `yourelement.component.html`

Use `[formGroup]` to reference form variable, and use `formControlName` to reference form's inner variable (both defined in TypeScrit file). Preferably, use `[value]` to reference some type of option ID.

```
<form [formGroup] = "uploadForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   . . .html
   <select class="form-control" formControlName="form_variable" required>
       <option *ngFor="let elem of list" [value]="elem.id">{{elem.nanme}}</option>
   </select>
   . . .
</form>
```

#### Logic file: `yourelement.component.ts`

In the initialization of `FormBuilder`object, in `ngOnInit()` function, set the default value you desire to be as default selected.

```js
. . .
// Remember to add imports of "FormsModule" and "ReactiveFormsModule" to app.module.ts
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
. . .

export class YourElementComponent implements OnInit {
  // <form> variable
  uploadForm: FormGroup;

  constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder ){}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.uploadForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          . . .
          form_variable: ['0'], // <--- Here is the "value" ID of default selected
          . . .
     });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First or all you are using ng-model which is considered to be an angularjs syntax. Use `[(ngModel)]` instead with the default value

**App.component.html**

```
<select [(ngModel)]='nrSelect' class='form-control'>
    <option value='47'>47</option>
    <option value='46'>46</option>
    <option value='45'>45</option>
</select>
```

**App.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
@Component({ 
    selector: 'my-app', 
    templateUrl: './app.component.html', 
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ] 
}) 

export class AppComponent { 
    nrSelect:string = "47" 
}
```

Comment: You've typed `nrSelect` as a string, and used a number literal, so I don't think this would compile

Comment: I'm using **Angular 9** and that's actually the only way I've found it working

Answer (score 7):

### HTML

```
<select class='form-control'>
    <option *ngFor="let option of options"
    [selected]="option === nrSelect"
    [value]="option">
        {{ option }}
    </option>
</select>
```

### Typescript

```
nrSelect = 47;
options = [41, 42, 47, 48];
```

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issues with Angular6 . After going through many posts. I had to import FormsModule as below in app.module.ts .

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```

Then my ngModel tag worked . Please try this.

```
<select [(ngModel)]='nrSelect' class='form-control'>                                                                
                                <option [ngValue]='47'>47</option>
                                    <option [ngValue]='46'>46</option>
                                    <option [ngValue]='45'>45</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way to do it to bind it with ngModel.

```
<select name="num" [(ngModel)]="number">
                <option *ngFor="let n of numbers" [value]="n">{{n}}</option>
              </select>
```

and in ts file add

```
number=47;
numbers=[45,46,47]
```

Comment: This works well but there is a small gotcha if you are not paying attention. Even though you did it here, it's not obvious that if the control is inside a form, you MUST include the name='something'. It won't work without it.

Answer (score 4):

i manage this by doing like this =>

```
<select class="form-control" 
        [(ngModel)]="currentUserID"
        formControlName="users">
        <option value='-1'>{{"select a user" | translate}}</option>
            <option 
            *ngFor="let user of users"
            value="{{user.id}}">
            {{user.firstname}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<select class="form-control" [value]="defaultSelectedCurrency" formControlName="currency">
<option *ngFor="let item of currency" [value]="item.value" [selected]="item.isSelected">{{item.key}}</option>
</select>

currency = [
    { key: 'USD', value: 'USD', isSelected: true },
    { key: 'AUD', value: 'AUD', isSelected: false }
  ];
  defaultSelectedCurrency: string;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.defaultSelectedCurrency = this.currency[0].value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use bellow like in angular 9

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="itemId"  formControlName="itemId" class="form-control" >
          <option [ngValue]="" disabled>Choose Gender</option>             
          <option *ngFor="let item of items"  [ngValue]="item .id" [selected]="item .id == this.id"  >
             {{item.name}}
          </option>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what mentioned before, you can use `[attr.selected]` directive to select a specific option, as follows:

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let program of programs" [attr.selected]="(member.programID == program.id)">
        {{ program.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using the same markup for editing an existing entity, or creating a brand new one (so far anyway).

I want to display a default-value that is "selected" in the select-elements when in creationMode, while displaying the values form the backend in editMode.

My solution is:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="entity.property" id="property" name="property" required>
  <option disabled hidden value="undefined">Enter prop</option>
  <option *ngFor="let prop of sortedProps" value="{{prop.value}}">{{prop.displayName}}</option>
</select>
```

for the regular available options I'm using a `sortedProps` Array to provide option choices. But that's not the important part here.

What did the trick for me is setting `value="undefined"` to let the angular-model-binding (?) select this option automatically when in creationMode. Not sure if its a hack, but does exactly what i want. No addtionally typeScript necessary.

Additionally, sepcifing `hidden` makes sure the option in my case is not selectable, while `required` makes sure the form is invalid unless something gets selected there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FormBuilder, you can also do this

In your component.html

```
<select formControlName="genero" id="genero" name="country" 
        class="form-control form-select" data-bs-placeholder="Género">
    <option value="F">Femenino</option>
    <option value="M">Masculino</option>
    <option value="O">Otro</option>
</select>
```

In your component.ts

```
formInfoAdmin = new FormGroup({
    genero: new FormControl('F'),
})
```

And your output would be

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<select [(ng-model)]='nrSelect' >                                                                
    <option [value]='47'>47</option>
    <option [value]='46'>46</option>
    <option [value]='45'>45</option>
</select>
```

---

Use square brackets for each option value

---

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me.  Note the selected option looks back at the component properties and if the truthy validates, you get the proper selection.

```
<select class="form-select" (change)="changeLookBackPeriod($event)">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let time_series_period of time_series_periods">
      <option [value]="time_series_period" [selected]="(time_series_period == lookback_period)"> {{ time_series_period }}</option>
    </ng-container>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

In the component.html file, you can simple use [ngModel] to set the default value and create an option for that.

Ex.1: Static option values

```
<select [ngModel]="0" class="form-control">
    <option value='0'>Default</option>
    <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Ex.2: Dynamic option values

```
<select [ngModel]="0" class="form-control">
    <option value='0'>Default</option>
    <option *ng-For="let item of list, let i = index"
        [value]='item.key'>
        {{item.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```