# How to set default selected object for select option in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying set default selected object for select option in angular 6.But it's not working

```
<select name="editUserType" class="form-select" id="editUserType" [(ngModel)]="updateModel.userType">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select User Type</option>
    <option *ngFor="let userType of userTypeList"  [selected ]="userType.code == updateModel.userType.code"  [ngValue]="userType">{{userType.description}}</option>
</select>
```

userType is a object I want to, when I load web page set default object for select option.

Comment: [(ngModel)]="updateModel.userType",since usertype is object no value will be set.I would suggest you to hardcode some value here and check like [(ngModel)]="Shalika" and for your information you cannot bind object only primitive types are possible.

Comment: Can you provide StackBlitz?

Comment: Click on the link below this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56346652/9292877

Answer (score 1):

set the default value from the component

```
constructor(){
  this.updateModel.userType = ""
}
```

Comment: Thank for the reply @sachila.But my concern is updateModel.userType  has a default value get by backend.It should be auto selected in the drop down.

Comment: set the ngvalue to value that u get from backend. like `[ngValue]="userType.code"`

Comment: is it possible to set [ngValue]="userType" like this ? I want to pass whole object to the backend.

Comment: then u need get the whole object from backend and assign.

Comment: yes I can assign whole object in backend.But default selected value not set using below code.[selected ]="userType.code == updateModel.userType.code" .Is there any way to set selected value ?

Comment: did u sort the issue ?

Comment: still no !! I set the value other than try to set the object.

Comment: can you create a stackBlitz