# How to put a default value to angular select?

Tags: angular

**Problem:**

In my angular application, I am using HTML select. I want to put a default value to my select. This is my code looks.

```
<div class="form-group" >
              <label>Receiver :</label>
              <div class="input-group input-group-alternative mb-3">
                <select class="custom-select" id="agent" formControlName="userid" *ngIf="!type"  >
                    <option value="0" [selected]="0">Select Reciver</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let agent of agents" [ngValue]="agent.agentId">{{agent.firstName}} {{agent.lastName}}-
                    {{agent.area}}</option>
                </select>
                <select class="custom-select" id="agent" formControlName="userid" *ngIf="type" [value]='0' >
                    <option value="0">Select Reciver</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let farmer of farmers" [ngValue]="farmer.farmerId">{{farmer.firstName}} {{farmer.lastName}}</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I tried almost all the answers in this particular question.

[Select default option value from typescript angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51009331/select-default-option-value-from-typescript-angular-6/51009366)

But it seems nothing to work. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Reactive Forms (because I see you have `formControlName="userid"` in there), then you can set the default when you create the "userid" control like so:

```
myForm = this.fb.group({
  userid: ['default_value']
})
```

If you instead used the FormControl constructor, then the first argument is the default value:

```
userid = new FormControl('default_value');
```

Take a look at the docs for [Reactive forms here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).