# Angular / Select / formControl / default value

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to find a way to mark the option as selected in my select but I am not successful.

I tried several solutions found over internet but couldn't find the right implementation.

Does any one have a working example, thanks.

Below (part of) my code

**.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="fgForm">
...
<select class="form-control" formControlName="country">
    <option value="" [ngValue]="null">Choose your country</option>
    <option 
        *ngFor="let oneCountry of selOptCountries;" 
        [ngValue]="oneCountry"
    >{{oneCountry.name}}</option>
</select>
</form>
```

**.ts (formControl)**

```
// The data comes from an API
this.selOptCountries = [
{"id": 2516, "name": "Austria", "iso2": "AT"},
{"id": 2519, "name": "Belgium", "iso2": "BE"},
{"id": 2523, "name": "Bulgaria", "iso2": "BG"},
{"id": 2601, "name": "Croatia", "iso2": "HR"},
...
{"id": 2636, "name": "Luxembourg", "iso2": "LU"}
...
];

this.fgForm = this.formBuilder.group({
'country': [
        {value: datas.country,disabled: false},
        [Validators.required]
    ],
});
```

**datas.country**

```
{id: 2636, name: "Luxembourg", iso2: "LU"}
```

Comment: check this:https://netbasal.com/understanding-the-comparefn-input-in-angular-v4-4a401ef4fc4c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the value with `datas.country` directly, write it as like this:

```js
value: this.selOptCountries.find(c => c.id === datas.country.id)
```

**Demo**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/object-option-item?file=src/app/app.component.ts

The `datas.country` object and the country object(Luxembourg) in the countries are not recognized as same though they have exactly same properties since every object in JavaScript is unique.

**From MDN**

---

In JavaScript, objects are a reference type. Two distinct objects are never equal, even if they have the same properties. Only comparing the same object reference with itself yields true.

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting your select option value as object instead of id etc then you need to use `compareWith` directive to compare the value.

```
<form [formGroup]="fgForm">
 <select class="form-control" formControlName="country" [compareWith]="selectedVal">
<option [ngValue]="">Choose your country</option>
<option 
    *ngFor="let oneCountry of selOptCountries;" 
    [ngValue]="oneCountry"
>{{oneCountry.name}}</option>
</select>
```

in .ts

```
selectedVal(valOne, valTwo ) : boolean {
  return valOne.id === valTwo.id;
}
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wqjr1j)

Answer (score 0):

The clean and correct way to do this is to use the ngModel binding on the select tag.

Here is an answer I submitted on another post, with reference and working Stackblitz example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64082745/450388